# A build function returned null Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

This is my problem and I don't know how can fix it. Please help me [image: error when I run app]

Github of this project: [here](https://github.com/tult1803/9code/tree/master/demo_api)

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           22.0s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
Waiting for iPhone SE (2nd generation) to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54630/tFUTjcfl640=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone SE (2nd generation)...
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<CalendarDetailModel>(dirty, state:
flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<CalendarDetailModel, AsyncSnapshot<CalendarDetailModel>>#836df):
flutter: A build function returned null.
flutter: The offending widget is:
flutter:   StreamBuilder<CalendarDetailModel>
flutter: Build functions must never return null.
flutter: To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return
flutter: "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return
flutter: "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   StreamBuilder<CalendarDetailModel>
flutter:   file:///Users/lethanhtu/Desktop/firebase_authentication/lib/ui/calendar_detail.dart:54:20
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:276:7)
flutter: #1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:297:4)
flutter: #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4516:7)
flutter: #3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:11)
flutter: #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4227:5)
flutter: #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4490:5)
flutter: #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
flutter: #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4485:5)
flutter: ...     Normal element mounting (39 frames)
flutter: #46     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3455:14)
flutter: #47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3223:18)
flutter: #48     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1162:36)
flutter: #49     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1147:20)
flutter: #50     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2612:19)
flutter: #51     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1140:11)
flutter: #52     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
flutter: #53     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1866:58)
flutter: #54     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:918:15)
flutter: #55     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1866:13)
flutter: #56     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
flutter: #57     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:427:5)
flutter: #58     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:79:12)
flutter: #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #60     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:135:11)
flutter: #61     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:375:11)
flutter: #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #63     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:452:13)
flutter: #64     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1443:12)
flutter: #65     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1352:20)
flutter: #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #75     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #79     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #83     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:207:11)
flutter: #84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #85     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11)
flutter: #86     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:480:7)
flutter: #87     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
flutter: #88     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14)
flutter: #89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #90     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #91     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #92     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #93     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1267:11)
flutter: #94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #95     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #97     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #98     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #99     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #101    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:556:15)
flutter: #102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #106    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #107    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #108    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #109    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #110    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #111    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #112    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #113    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #114    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3219:13)
flutter: #115    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #116    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:700:15)
flutter: #117    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #118    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #119    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #120    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #121    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #122    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #123    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #124    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #125    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #126    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:13)
flutter: #127    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
flutter: #128    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:167:13)
flutter: #129    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1630:7)
flutter: #130    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
flutter: #131    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:402:19)
flutter: #132    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:865:13)
flutter: #133    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
flutter: #134    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
flutter: #135    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
flutter: #136    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:861:7)
flutter: (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
flutter:
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Status code is 200
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
#0      new CalendarDetailModel (package:firebaseauthentication/models/calendar_detail_model.dart:26:40)
#1      CalendarDetailRepository.fetchRoom.<anonymous closure> (package:firebaseauthentication/resources/calendar_detail_repository.dart:38:23)
#2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:289:8)
#3      CalendarDetailRepository.fetchRoom (package:firebaseauthentication/resources/calendar_detail_repository.dart:35:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      CalendarDetailBloc.loadRoom (package:firebaseauthentication/blocs/calendar_detail_bloc.dart:16:36)
#5      CalendarDetailsState.initState (package:firebaseauthentication/ui/calendar_detail.dart:35:10)
#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4649:58)
#7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4485:5)
#8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/<…>

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<CalendarDetailModel>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<CalendarDetailModel, AsyncSnapshot<CalendarDetailModel>>#836df):
A build function returned null.

The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<CalendarDetailModel>
Build functions must never return null.

To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<CalendarDetailModel> file:///Users/lethanhtu/Desktop/firebase_authentication/lib/ui/calendar_detail.dart:54:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:276:7)
#1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:297:4)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4516:7)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4227:5)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Please post the code of this particular page.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear about what the issue is. In you `StreamBuilder` you are not awlays returning something. You have:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
    ...
  }
```

which only returns something on an error or when data is available. However, there won't always be data available or an error, so you have to return something when neither of these conditions are true.

Simply adding `return CircularProgressIndicator();` outside of these `if-else` blocks or in an `else` statement will solve your issue.

Ex.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
```

Following the instructions that these errors provide can save you a lot of time and takes away the need to ask here on SO.